# How to group dates based on day?

Tags: python

To simplify my problem, I have dates like these:

```
2019-10-05 # Day 1 => starting point
2019-10-07 # Day 3
2019-10-07 # Day 3
2019-10-09 # Day 5
2019-10-10 # Day 6
2019-10-10 # Day 6
```

result should be: `{1: ['2019-10-05'], 3: ['2019-10-07', '2019-10-07'], and so on...}`

I feel that there is a module in Python (probably Collections?) that can solve for this but I don't exactly know what terminology should I use that is applicable to this problem other than grouping dates in day.

Comment: what is the type of data is it a text? a list of dates?

Comment: Yes, a list of dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with some amount of conversion between strings and dates ([`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) does the heavy lifting)... you could do this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from collections import defaultdict

# the date format (for strptime)
fmt = "%Y-%m-%d"

startdate = datetime.strptime('2019-10-05', fmt).date()

# the dates as strings
date_str_list = [
    "2019-10-07", # Day 3
    "2019-10-07", # Day 3
    "2019-10-09", # Day 5
    "2019-10-10", # Day 6
    "2019-10-10"  # Day 6
]

# converting to date objects
date_list = [datetime.strptime(date_str, fmt).date() for date_str in date_str_list]

res = defaultdict(list)
for date in date_list:
    res[(date - startdate).days + 1].append(str(date))

print(res)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {3: ['2019-10-07', '2019-10-07'], 
#     5: ['2019-10-09'], 6: ['2019-10-10', '2019-10-10']})
```

where i use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) as the container.

the difference of two `date` object is a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object; `.days` gives the number of days thereof.

Comment: use generator expression instead of list comprehensive `date_list = (......)`, you could use a normal dictionary and `res.setdefault((date - startdate).days + 1, []).append(str(date))`

Comment: @CharifDZ agreed for the generator expression (depending on what else needs to be done with these dates). but i prefer `defaultdict` to `setdefault` (i vaguely remember it to be more efficient...).